# What does "foo = bar1, bar2" do?

Tags: c, expression, undefined-behavior

I made some code that looks like this:

```
int foo, bar1 = 4, bar2 = 7;

foo = bar1, bar2; // Look at this expression.

printf("%d", foo);
```

Compiled it with GCC, with **-Wall** and **-Wextra**.
The output was `4`.

Apart from being ugly, is this expression undefined behaviour, or is `foo` always set to `bar1`?

Comment: It should be outputting <strike>7</strike>4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator "In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type)." but assignment is a higher precedence, so it assigns first then discards.

Comment: @PaulTomblin True, but I think `,` has lower precedence than `=`.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Its also at the bottom of the precedence chart (last I checked) so in the OP's question the assignment operator is taking precedence first, and the eval of `bar2` is essentially worthless.

Comment: Ah, right you are, @ChrisJester-Young

Comment: putting `foo = (bar1, bar2);` instead makes it output `7`, but gives a warning.

Comment: @Zupoman with parens that should yield `bar2`'s value into `foo`. And the warning should essentially be that `bar1`s value is unused in the expression (or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

It is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), mostly useful with side-effecting expressions like `foo = (bar1++, f(bar2));` which increments `bar1`,  call function `f` with `bar2` and set its result to `foo`

<sup>In *C* the comma operator has lower precedence than assignment.</sup>

In general `e1,e2` (in expression context) evaluates the left operand `e1`, *discards* its result, then evaluate the right operand `e2` and gives the value of the right operand (as the value of the entire `e1,e2` expression).

Ocaml has the `;` operator, Scheme has `begin`, Lisp has `progn` for similar purposes (evaluating two or several sub-expressions for side effects, and giving the last as the entire result).

Answer (score 1):

In that expression you are using the `,` operator which evaluates it operands from left-to-right and returns the last.  So it evaluates `foo = bar1` and then `bar2`.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
foo = bar1;
```

for deeper understanding,

```
int foo = barx, * barp;
```

Here `,` operator means

```
int foo = barx;
int *barp;
```